# NIC bonding using VirtualBox not working properly

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, oracle-linux, bonding

I am trying to configure NIC bonding using a VirtualBox oracle environment. I enabled two network adapters from the VirtualBox interface and the machine is configured in Bridged mode. I configured the two interfaces and also configured a bond0 interface. I configured the bonding as mode=1. Which is the active-backup configuration. I am having the following issues.

eth0 = 10.11.17.110

eth1 = 10.11.17.112

bond0 = 10.11.17.115

1. I can no longer ping eth0 or eth1 from outside the VirtualBox.
2. I can ping the bond0 from outside the VirtualBox only when eth0 is up. If I disable eth0, I can no longer ping bond0 from outside the VirtualBox. /proc/net/bonding/bond0 file still shows that the active port is now eth1. But I still can't ping.
   [image: cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0]
3. I was able to SSH on eth0 previously. I cannot do that either after this configuration.

Can someone please explain why this all might be happening and what might the solution be?